# Monitor output and weight layer means during model.fit training in Tensorflow Keras. Display metric from train_step, Not just at the end of each epoch

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Most of the methods I see use the callback to show stats at the end of each epoch. I am looking to show constantly updated stats from each step, along with the rest of the metrics.

This is what I've been trying so far.

```
class CustomModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        # Unpack the data. Its structure depends on your model and
        # on what you pass to `fit()`.
        x, y = data

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(x, training=True)  # Forward pass
            # Compute the loss value
            # (the loss function is configured in `compile()`)
            loss = self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred, regularization_losses=self.losses)

        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
        # Update metrics (includes the metric that tracks the loss)
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)
        # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value
        returnDict = {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}

        returnDict['robertaNorm'] = tf.norm(self.get_layer(index=2).get_weights()[-1])
        returnDict['qtNorm'] = tf.norm(self.get_layer(index=3).get_weights()[-1])
        returnDict['ptNorm'] = tf.norm(self.get_layer(index=4).get_weights()[-1])

        returnDict['qFF'] = tf.norm(self.get_layer(index=25).get_weights()[0])
        returnDict['pFF'] = tf.norm(self.get_layer(index=26).get_weights()[0])
        returnDict['qFF2'] = tf.norm(self.get_layer(index=27).get_weights()[0])
        returnDict['pFF2'] = tf.norm(self.get_layer(index=28).get_weights()[0])

        # tf.norm(model.get_layer('qffPost_2').get_weights()[0])

        return returnDict
```

However, I get error messages saying that they can't be accessed in the graph.

I also tried

`returnDict['qFF2'] = tf.norm(self.layers[27].get_weights()[0])`

And got the same results.